# Next button will be disabled when user enter invalid date or month using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github

I have a input fields of where credit card information is entered. I copy this code from this link [Card Js](https://cardjs.co.uk/)

I want that when user enter less than month or year then next button will be disabled

This is html code where user enter a information of credit card

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
<div class="card-js form-group has-label col-sm-8">

  <!-- Card number -->
  <input class="card-number form-control" name="card_number" placeholder="Enter your card number" autocomplete="off" required>

  <!-- Name on card -->
  <input class="name form-control" id="card_holder_name" name="card_holder_name" placeholder="Enter the name on your card" autocomplete="off" required>

  <!-- Card expiry (element that is displayed) -->
  <input class="expiry form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>

  <!-- Card expiry - Month (hidden) -->
  <input  class="expiry-month exp" name="card_exp_month" id="card_exp_month" required>

  <!-- Card expiry - Year (hidden) -->
  <input class="expiry-year exp" name="card_exp_year" id="card_exp_year"  required>

  <!-- Card CVC -->
  <input class="cvc form-control" name="card_cvc" autocomplete="off" required>

</div>
<?php
  $month= date('n');
  $year= date('y');
 ?> 
  <input type="text" name="curr_month" id="curr_month" value="<?php echo $month;?>"/>
  <input type="text" name="curr_year" id="curr_year" value="<?php echo $year;?>"/>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<input type='button' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd' name='next' value='Next' id="billing_nxtBtn"/>
</div>
```

This is cardjs code [link](https://github.com/CardJs/CardJs/blob/master/card-js.min.js) where all working in input fields

I am trying like this

```
$(".exp").on('input', function() {
var exp_month = $("#card_exp_month").val();
var exp_year = $("#card_exp_year").val();

var curr_month = $("#curr_month").val();
var curr_year = $("#curr_year").val();

 $("#billing_nxtBtn").prop('disabled', exp_year < curr_year || (exp_year == curr_year && exp_month < curr_month));
 });
```

Comment: try jQuery  `.on('change')` instead?

Comment: Try casting all your variables into integers by doing `Number()`.

Comment: can u explain it with code?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is invalid, you should add `not` to your condition.

Here's working code -

```js
$(".exp").on('input', function() {
  
  var exp_month = Number($("#card_exp_month").val());
  var exp_year = Number($("#card_exp_year").val());

  var curr_month = Number($("#curr_month").val());
  var curr_year = Number($("#curr_year").val());
  
  $("#billing_nxtBtn").prop('disabled', !(exp_year > curr_year || (exp_year == curr_year && exp_month > curr_month)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/CardJs/CardJs/blob/master/card-js.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-sm-12">
  <div class="card-js form-group has-label col-sm-8">

    <!-- Card number -->
    <input class="card-number form-control" name="card_number" placeholder="Enter your card number" autocomplete="off" required>

    <!-- Name on card -->
    <input class="name form-control" id="card_holder_name" name="card_holder_name" placeholder="Enter the name on your card" autocomplete="off" required>

    <!-- Card expiry (element that is displayed) -->
    <input class="expiry form-control" autocomplete="off" required>

    <!-- Card expiry - Month (hidden) -->
    <input class="expiry-month exp" name="card_exp_month" placeholder="exp month" id="card_exp_month" required>

    <!-- Card expiry - Year (hidden) -->
    <input class="expiry-year exp" name="card_exp_year" placeholder="exp year" id="card_exp_year" required>

    <!-- Card CVC -->
    <input class="cvc form-control" name="card_cvc" placeholder="cvv" autocomplete="off" required>

  </div>
    <input type="text" name="curr_month" placeholder="current month" class="exp" id="curr_month" />
    <input type="text" name="curr_year" placeholder="current year" class="exp" id="curr_year"" />
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
  <input type='button' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-rose btn-wd' name='next' value='Next' id="billing_nxtBtn" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support.. but issue is that in your code when user enter a exp month which greater than currrent month then next button will be disabled.. I want that exp month is less than current month then next button is disabled...is it possible its working in this condition?

Comment: next button is still  disabled

Comment: @Arslan i've enabled next button for valid input only, updated answer as per requirement